# Encoding polyline algorithms in java

Tags: java, google-maps, polyline

The following algorithm is used with Google Maps: 
http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm.html

Are there any alternatives? The purpose is to encode geodetic polylines for transfer from server to a client.

In the case of Google's approach, what is the best implementation in java?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found this site: [Encoding polylines for Google Maps](http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/GoogleMaps/EncodePolyline/).

It implements Google Maps API polygon and polyline algorithm in Java and other languages.

Don't know if it could be useful to you.